# Using Google Chart API to create pie chart from MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to use the Google Chart API to create a Pie Chart using data from my database. My database has two columns, one is the ID, one is the major. For the rows, I have the corresponding IDs and some majors. I used PHP to total up each major and then convert it to JSON. My data looks formatted correctly in JSON, but for some reason the pie chart only shows MAJOR and has 2 (100%) as the number. It doesn't seem to be reading the totals of the majors correctly and I don't see why. I've done some searching but can't find people with a similar problem.

Here is the JSON that is outputted

```
    {"cols":[{"label":"Major","type":"string"},{"label":"CS","type":"number"},{"label":"CIS","type":"number"},{"label":"Other","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"MAJOR"},{"v":2},{"v":1},{"v":2}]}]}
```

Here's my PHP

```
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=".$dbname.";", $username, $password);

    $query = $db->query("SELECT 'MAJOR' as 'Major', SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Computer Science',1,0)) as CS, SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Computer Information Systems',1,0)) as CIS, SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Other',1,0)) as Other FROM ages");


    $rows = array();
    $table = array();

    $table['cols'] = array(
        array('label' => 'Major', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'CS', 'type' => 'number'),
        array('label' => 'CIS', 'type' => 'number'),
        array('label' => 'Other', 'type' => 'number')
    );


    while($r = $query->fetch()){
        $temp = array();
        $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Major']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['CS']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['CIS']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Other']);

        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;

    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);

    echo $jsonTable;
```

And here's the Javascript that loads the chart and uses the JSON data

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getData.php",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't `SELECT 'MAJOR' as 'Major'` be just `SELECT MAJOR as Major` ?

Comment: @82Tuskers Now only Computer Science is being displayed with 2, which is correct, but it isn't displaying the rest of my data.

Comment: @82Tuskers It seems to display only whatever the last major that was entered instead of all of them for some reason.

Comment: can you please add a group by 1 here in the end: `"... 'Other',1,0)) as Other FROM ages group by 1 `.

Comment: @82Tuskers Some minor progress, now Computer Science is the only one that is displayed, despite what the last major that was entered into the database.

Comment: And here is what the JSON file displays `{"cols":[{"label":"Major","type":"string"},{"label":"CS","type":"number"},{"label":"CIS","type":"number"},{"label":"Other","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"Computer Information Systems"},{"v":0},{"v":6},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"Computer Science"},{"v":3},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"Other"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":3}]}]}`

Comment: looks like you have what you need ? Its says: CIS has 6, CS has 3 and other has 3 too. Can you confirm ?

Comment: @82Tuskers it still isn't the correct format for google's API to use it. Here is an example from Google.

`{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}`